# Laravel: How to use alerts in Voyager admin panel?

Tags: laravel, voyager

How to use alerts in  voyager? any example? I want to show alert when post submitting with empty fields.

- Voyager Version:  v0.11.14

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Voyager uses [toastr](https://github.com/oriceon/toastr-5-laravel) Library, and to use it simply you can fire it as an event using following ways :

```
Toastr::warning($message, $title = null, $options = []) - add a warning toast
Toastr::error($message, $title = null, $options = []) - add an error toast
Toastr::info($message, $title = null, $options = []) - add an info toast
Toastr::success($message, $title = null, $options = []) - add a success toast
Toastr::add($type: warning|error|info|success, $message, $title = null, $options = []) - add a toast
Toastr::clear() - clear all current toasts
```

Answer (score 8):

From a controller you can do something like this:

```
return redirect('path')->with(['message' => "Your Success Message", 'alert-type' => 'success']);
```

Or:

```
return redirect('path')->with(['message' => "Your Error Message", 'alert-type' => 'error']);
```